# Spigot-Bungeecord Plugin Messaging not working

Tags: java

I am trying to make a plugin that has a 'global' configuration file. Right now, I'm trying to use Plugin Messaging to send the entire configuration file through a string, to another server. I have followed the guide at https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/bukkit-bungee-plugin-messaging-channel/ and have put my own little twist on what is sent. I'm trying to send the plugin message within a spigot plugin so maybe that is the problem. Here is the code is a summary of the code I use to send it (I took out readFile(), clearFile() and writeFile(), let me know if you want those):

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements PluginMessageListener {
public void onEnable() {
    this.getServer().getMessenger().registerOutgoingPluginChannel(this, "BungeeCord");
    this.getServer().getMessenger().registerIncomingPluginChannel(this, "BungeeCord", this);
}

public void onDisable() {}

public void updateConfig() {
    String updateConfig = "";
    for (String s : readFile(this.getDataFolder() + "/config.yml")) {
        if (updateConfig.equals("")) {
            updateConfig = s;
        } else {
            updateConfig = updateConfig + " |n| " + s;
        }
    }
    Bukkit.getLogger().info("Sending config update...");
    sendUpdateconfig(updateConfig);
}

public void sendUpdateconfig(String update) {
    ByteArrayDataOutput out = ByteStreams.newDataOutput();
    try {

        out.writeUTF("Forward");
        out.writeUTF("ALL");
        out.writeUTF("FooServer");

        ByteArrayOutputStream msgbytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream msgout = new DataOutputStream(msgbytes);
        msgout.writeUTF(update);
        msgout.writeShort(295);

        out.writeShort(msgbytes.toByteArray().length);
        out.write(msgbytes.toByteArray());

        Player player = Iterables.getLast(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers());
        player.getServer().sendPluginMessage(this, "BungeeCord", out.toByteArray());
        Bukkit.getLogger().info("Sent " + update);
        Bukkit.getLogger().info("Short sent: 295");
        Bukkit.getLogger().info("Sent through player " + player.getName());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPluginMessageReceived(String channel, Player player, byte[] message) {
    Bukkit.getLogger().info("Recieved message...");
    if (!channel.equals("BungeeCord")) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        Bukkit.getLogger().info("Recieved message...");
        ByteArrayDataInput in = ByteStreams.newDataInput(message);
        String subChannel = in.readUTF();
        if (!subChannel.equals("FooServer")) {
            Bukkit.getLogger().info("Loading message....");
            short len = in.readShort();
            byte[] msgbytes = new byte[len];
            in.readFully(msgbytes);

            DataInputStream msgin = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(msgbytes));
            String somedata = msgin.readUTF();
            short somenumber = msgin.readShort();

            if (somenumber == 295) {
                Bukkit.getLogger().info("Updating config...");
                String[] toWrite = somedata.split(" |n| ");
                String path = (this.getDataFolder() + "/config.yml");
                clearFile(path);
                for (String s : toWrite) {
                    writeFile(path, s);
                }
                Bukkit.getLogger().info("Config updated!");
            }
        } else {
            Bukkit.getLogger().info("Message sent by this plugin.");
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The way I send the message is just by calling, updateConfig(); When that is called, onPluginMessageReceived is never run. 
Is there something I'm doing wrong? Can plugin messages only be sent by a bungeecord plugin? Thanks in advance. If you have any questions about the code, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Don't work beacause it's write ( String server to send to, or ALL to send to every server (except the one sending the plugin message)) ! For use it you can use our own channel or redis